# Is there a standard place for the Salt and IV in an AES encrypted file

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

This was all coded in C#, but I don't believe that makes much difference for this question.

Currently I'm mirroring the OpenSSL functionality for Key/IV/Salt generation and placement.  I just want to know, is there a standard somewhere I should adhere to?

Currently I get the salt from the first 16 bytes (minus the "Salted__" designation).  Then I use the salt and password to generate the key and IV.  On the encrypting end I'm doing the same, with a randomly generated Salt.

Is that an industry standard?  Or if I send this to someone with a different product, will they likely not be able to decrypt my files (even though the password we derive everything from might be the same)?

Also as a side note, is this a secure way to generate the iv?  Are there any other security concerns?

This question is the result of conversations with an outside entity that has given me a key instead of a password.  Wouldn't that make the salt redundant, since there will be no variation in key?

Comment: I think you will get a better response on http://security.blogoverflow.com/

Comment: @Marko blogoverflow? :P

Comment: Copy and paste error i meant http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

> Currently I'm mirroring the OpenSSL functionality for Key/IV/Salt generation and placement. I just want to know, is there a standard somewhere I should adhere to?

There are multiple standards, but OpenSSL is proprietary. Known standards are CMS and OpenPGP, both standards are free and easy to find.

> Is that an industry standard? Or if I send this to someone with a different product, will they likely not be able to decrypt my files.

Well, they can always download openssl of course. There is the chance that you are now using OpenSSL's proprietary key [EVP_BytesToKey](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) derivation too. It can be implemented, but it is severely non-standard - there should be PBKDF2 implemented by OpenSSL as well.

> Also as a side note, is this a secure way to generate the iv? Are there any other security concerns?

It is secure as long as the salt (and thus the generated data key) is always different. The biggest security concern is the missing integrity / authentication. You should always add a MAC for communication protocols.

> This question is the result of conversations with an outside entity that has given me a key instead of a password. Wouldn't that make the salt redundant, since there will be no variation in key?

The key doesn't have to vary as long as you create a random IV for each encryption.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  OpenSSL is not proprietary though, it's open source.  Could you provide some explanation of the two standards you referenced?  For example, what does CMS say about the location of the Salt/IV?  I've looked up the rfc, but I don't see reference to that

Comment: The problem with those standards is that they are pretty complex, and they are mostly used together with asymmetric encryption. If you use hybrid encryption then you can use a different symmetric key each time, so there is no need to store the IV. What I meant regarding OpenSSL is that it's symmetric encryption method does not comply to a written down / agreed upon standard. So it is proprietary to OpenSSL even though OpenSSL is not the property of anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Salt and/or IV are usually prepended to the cyphertext.  The receiver knows that they are there and what size they are, so they can easily be removed.  In your case, you are generating the IV, so you only need to prepend the fixed length salt when encrypting.